# Calling array element with index from an array inside the array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

I want to make a survey app in JS and I have a the following code in the main:

```
for(var questionNumber in questionsAndAnswers.allQuestions){
      for(var i in questionsAndAnswers.allQuestions[questionNumber]){
        console.log(questionsAndAnswers.allQuestions[questionNumber].question);
        console.log(questionsAndAnswers[questionNumber+1]);
    } 
}
```

And this code in the config:

```
const questionsAndAnswers = {
    "allQuestions": [
        { "question": "Write your first question here",
        },
        { "question": "Write your second question here",
        },
        { "question": "Write your third question here",
      }
     ],
    "answerOne": [
        "1.This is the first answer",
        "1.This is the second answer",
        "1.This is the third answer"
        ],
    "answerTwo": [
        "2.This is the first answer",
        "2.This is the second answer",
        "2.This is the third answer"
      ],
     "answerThree": [
        "3.This is the first answer",
        "3.This is the second answer",
        "3.This is the third answer"
      ]
}
```

And then this comes out:

```
Write your first question here
undefined
Write your second question here
undefined
Write your third question here
undefined
```

I want to do this: when the first question is asked, only the first answers to appear, but when I call `console.log(questionsAndAnswers[questionNumber+1]);`Undefined appears.
I tried many options, but the main problem is separating the questions from answers and dinamically adding a question + answer, when the `config` is changed, without changing the `main`.
I would be very greatfull, if you could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to store the question & answers in same object. `{ question: "abc", answers: ["abc", "def", ghi"], correct: 0}`.

Comment: This works. It was so easy. Thank you! How can I select you as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used what [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) said:

> I suggest to store the question & answers in same object. { question:
>   "abc", answers: ["abc", "def", ghi"], correct: 0}.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`questionNumber` is an integer representing index. So for the first item, `questionNumber === 0`, you're trying to get the answer from `questionsAndAnswers[0 + 1] === questionsAndAnswers[1]`. Since there is no property "1" on your object, it's undefined.

If you want to use a data structure similar to this, I'd suggest something like:

```
for(var questionNumber in questionsAndAnswers.allQuestions){
  console.log(questionsAndAnswers.allQuestions[questionNumber].question);
  for(var i in questionsAndAnswers.allAnswers[questionNumber]){
    console.log(questionsAndAnswers[questionNumber][i]);
  } 
}

const questionsAndAnswers = {
  "allQuestions": [
    { "question": "Write your first question here" },
    { "question": "Write your second question here" },
    { "question": "Write your third question here" }
  ],
  "allAnswers": [
    [
      "1.This is the first answer",
      "1.This is the second answer",
      "1.This is the third answer"
    ],
    [
      "2.This is the first answer",
      "2.This is the second answer",
      "2.This is the third answer"
    ],
    [
      "3.This is the first answer",
      "3.This is the second answer",
      "3.This is the third answer"
    ]
  ]
}
```

However, I'd encourage you to explore different ways of organizing your data structures, as this way seems a little strange. Maybe try creating separate objects for questions and answers, or nesting answers under questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rethink your data model.
Your questionsAndAnswers is an object, which means you access a question not by an integer, rather by a key ("answerOne", "answerTwo",...).
Thus `questionsAndAnswers[questionNumber+1]` is not working.
It must be something like `questionsAndAnswers["answerOne"]`.

However I would advise you to save the answers in your question object.

```
{
    "question": "Write your first question here",
    "answers": [...]
}
```